# Can resign be followed by a to-infinitive?

Tags: verbs, reflexives, catenative-verbs

I was looking at Wiktionary's list of catenative verbs and noticed the list was far from exhaustive. I added "deign," and, having finished reading the list, I was trying to think of others to add. The first thought I had was "resign," but upon searching multiple dictionaries and other lists of catenative verbs, I have come up with no evidence of this.

I am thinking of the sentence, "I finally resigned to go to the play despite my initial reservations."

Now, some sites list "resign (oneself) to," but this is clearly different.

Is "resign oneself to [verb]" truly catenative? And is "resign to [verb]" a possible construction?

Comment: I don't think so. Without the "myself" it sounds like you quit your job.

Comment: Generally _resigned to_ governs a gerund, not an infinitive. _She's resigned to working Saturdays for the next couple months_.

Comment: @JohnLawler ah yes I believe that's where I was trying to get. Thank you

Comment: "To working Saturdays for the next couple months" is not a gerund. It's a preposition phrase headed by the prep "to" with a gerund-participial clause as complement of the head.

Comment: I found "deign" in my list of catenative verbs; it requires a _to_- infinitival complement.  "Resign" is not a catenative verb.  "Resign to [verb]" with the meaning you cite is non-standard. It's adjectival use in "I was finally resigned to go to the play despite my initial reservations" is common enough. though.